# Avoiding time consuming data loading during Fragment rotation

Tags: android

I want to avoid time consuming data loading during `Fragment` rotation.

```
public class WatchlistFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            data = getTimeConsumingData();          
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "savedInstanceState is not null!");
            // Avoid performing time consuming data operation during rotation changes.
            // But I never have chance to reach here !?!?
            data = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("data");
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
    }

    public String[] getTimeConsumingData() {
        Log.i(TAG, "WatchlistFragment getTimeConsumingData");
        return new String[] { "A", "B", "C"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "WatchlistFragment onSaveInstanceState");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArray("data", data);
    }

    private String[] data = null;
    private static final String TAG = WatchlistFragment.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

Strangely, `savedInstanceState` in `onActivityCreated` is always null even I perform several rotation.

Note, I prefer not to use `setRetainInstance(true)` as described [Android Fragments Retaining Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853389/android-fragments-retaining-data) The author is using `onSaveInstanceState`. Just that I'm not sure why mine doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use the new, super clever, Loader pattern, it's easy to implement and let the system handle all this for you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Answer (score 0):

just use `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragment and check for `savedInstanceState==null` and dont override `onSaveInstanceState`

**UPDATE**

```
 private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setReatainInstance(true);
    if(adapter==null){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getTimeConsumingData());
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you have complete code example? As I try to have `setRetainInstance` set to true, but Fragment still created each time there is rotation.

Comment: Strangely. I have `setReatainInstance(true);` in `onActivityCreated`. Not working. Moving it to `onCreate` is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using loaders, Use loadermanager.destory(loader_id) after loading the data.It will wont load again for config changes.