# Advice on how to fix frame skipping in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So I've just noticed that my app is skipping quite a few frames when running in the emulator. This is my first app and I did some reading on the topic and found that I might not be starting the activities correctly. However, my activities are loaded through the settings menu and I  don't know where this is in my code. If this is a big issue it would be appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction in relation to my specific code?
https://github.com/addrum/Calculate

I can post code here in preference if needed.

Edit: It appears to skip frames on the splash activity:

```
package com.main.androidcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openMain = new Intent("com.main.androidcalculator.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMain);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: i think you should write piece of code which is relevant about your problem because SO people are lazy.

Comment: On what activity does it skip some frames?

Comment: All of your activities look fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "skipping frames"?  Frames of a video?  There is nothing in your splash activity about a video, so I'm assuming that's not it ...

Comment: In my LogCat in Eclipse I get the message:     10-22 21:27:57.495: I/Choreographer(2243): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I also noticed I get it when switching back and forth between main and the settings/about/help activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the emulator is just too slow.
Your code works fine on a real device. I've tested on GS3.
Maybe [ProgressBar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java/) is just too heavy for the emulator. 
The view has animation and a lot of stuffs.
(Remove the ProgressBar and the issue's gone!)

See also:
[Choreographer(639): Skipped 50 frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963969/choreographer639-skipped-50-frames)

Comment: Or image resources are way to big: simply showing six 300kB PNG files can introduce a 20 second delay on Android. All you see is a white screen and the skipped frames warning.