# what is the Choreographer in android studio emulator and why is it complaining?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting the following log in the android studio Run window:

I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I am logging everything I am doing in this single activity app. It only has 2 buttons with callbacks and a textView. I have no clue as to what this might be.

Comment: Android 4.1's "Project Butter" introduced the `Choreographer`, which helps lock widget-based GUIs to a 60fps update cycle. That message is telling you that you have done something that has blocked the main application thread for 31 frames, or roughly 500 ms. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963969/choreographer639-skipped-50-frames and several hundred other questions on this subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of Choreographer messages in Logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat)